# Paginate the results from Amazon product search

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

I am using the gem [amazon_product](https://github.com/hakanensari/amazon_product) for searching the books in Amazon.
The search is perfectly fine but it gets me only a list of first 10 books.
I want to get all the search results and paginate them. How can I do this?

My code looks like this,

```
req = AmazonProduct["us"]
req.configure do |c|
  c.key    = "KEY"
  c.secret = "SECRET_KEY"
  c.tag    = "TAG" 
end
resp = req.search("Books", :power => params[:book][:search_term], :sort => "reviewrank")
@books = resp.to_hash["Items"]["Item"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From their API page at - http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

They have "RelatedItemPage" and "ItemPage"

You should give this a try

```
resp = req.search("Books", :power => params[:book][:search_term], :itemPage => 20)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: max itemPage on API version 2011-08-01 (current) is set to 10 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/PagingThroughResults.html